# how to pass multiple values to ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, asp.net-mvc-4

Right now I have one value being passed and returned to a text box. I want to add multiple text boxes and pass all the values from the controller to ajax function to be displayed in the text box when the page is load.

```
Controller:

    public string GetFormData()
    {
       //using Linq query and EF
        Form form = db.Forms.Find(1);
        if (form == null)
        {
            return "";
        }
        else

            return form.username;

    }
```

AJAX:

```
 $("#btnSaveForm").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $('#Result2').html("<img src='/Images/loading.gif' />");


        $.post($("#frmform").attr("action"), $("#frmform").serialize(), function (result) {
            if (result != null) {
                $('#Result2').html(result);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Your code will still work if you put the new textfields within `<form id="frmform" ...></form>` tag. You need to capture them in your controller.

Comment: yes, it does work but i wanted to know how to pass different values to ajax for different text box fields

Comment: If you want to send custom fields as POST in ajax you can try like this: `$.post($("#frmform").attr("action"), {'field1':$("#field1").val(),'field2':$("#field1").val()}, function (result) {...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to return JSON result. Consider this simple example:

**Model**

```
public class JSONTestModel
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public bool IsMarried { get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult TestJSON()
    {
        var model = new JSONTestModel()
        {
            Name = "John Smith",
            IsMarried = true,
            Age = 35
        };

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TestJSON(JSONTestModel model)
    {
        // YOUR CODE HERE

        return Json(model);
    }
```

Please note, the post method returns JSON result. This will serialize the object you pass to Json.

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    @Html.EditorForModel()

    <input id="save-data" type="button" value="Save" />
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#save-data').click(function () {
            $.post($("form").attr("action"), $("form").serialize(), function (result) {
                if (result != null) {
                    alert('Name - ' + result.Name);
                    alert('IsMarried - ' + result.IsMarried);
                    alert('Age - ' + result.Age);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The `result` parameter is the json object you returned in the controller.

Hope it helps!